# Idempotent ,Involuntary and orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices

[image]

In this I am not getting any start can anyone provide me a hint

Comment: What is adj? I would have a guess, but then you could not take the absolute value of it ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen adjoint matrix

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

- $A$ is idempotent, so  $A^2=A$,
- $B$ is involutory, so $B^2=I$ (and hence $B^{-1}=B$),
- $C$ is orthogonal, so $C^{-1}=C^T$.

Actually, $A$ is a joke: It is not only idempotent, but also invertible. Hence from $A^2=A$ we can conclude $A=A^2A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$. This allows us to drop $A$ altogether.

**(A)** We have
$$(ABC)^{-1}=(BC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}= C^{-1}B$$
and 
$$ (AB^TC)^T=(B^TC)^T=C^TB^{TT}=C^{-1}B$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nice explnation  Can you explain option D